# how do I compare a date in case statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, case

I want to compare date data and then assign a new name, here is my query

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,HIRE_DATE
CASE
WHEN HIRE_DATE < DATE('1987-09-01')THEN 'JUNIOR'
WHEN HIRE_DATE BETWEEN DATE('1987-05-01') AND DATE('1987-08-31') THEN 'MID LEVEL SENIOR'
WHEN HIRE_DATE > DATE('1987-05-01') THEN 'SENIOR'
END AS 'experience_level' 
FROM employees;
```

there is some error that occurred. 
what is my problem?

```
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,HIRE_DATE
CASE
WHEN HIRE_DATE < DATE('1987-09-01')THEN 'JUNIOR'
WHEN HIRE_DATE BETWEEN DATE('1987-05-01') AND DATE('1987-08-31') THEN 'MID LEVEL SENIOR'
WHEN HIRE_DATE > DATE('1987-05-01') THEN 'SENIOR'
END AS 'experience_level' 
FROM employees LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE
>       WHEN HIRE_DATE < DATE('1987-09-01')THEN 'JUNIOR'
>       WHEN HIRE_DATE BETWEEN D' at line 2

Comment: If hire_date is a date datatype then the Date function in DATE('1987-08-31') is unnecessary - mysql will do an implicit conversion.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing "," after "HIRE_DATE". i.e. your query should be like:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,HIRE_DATE,
CASE
  WHEN HIRE_DATE < DATE('1987-09-01')THEN 'JUNIOR'
  WHEN HIRE_DATE BETWEEN DATE('1987-05-01') AND DATE('1987-08-31') THEN 'MID LEVEL SENIOR'
  WHEN HIRE_DATE > DATE('1987-05-01') THEN 'SENIOR'
END AS 'experience_level' 
FROM employees;
```

Comment: but then it shows another error, unexpected token near experience level

Comment: refresh your UI and try again. Hope the issue has no concern with the token